# Running Express Server on CPanel (Shared Host)

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I have a back-end server on heroku (and it works fine),

I want to move the back-end server form heroku to my website,

I use "Setup Node.js APP" option on CPanel to create the app,

But it wont work! I can't figure it out what should I do?!

I tried to run very simple server but even that wont work for me:

when I run start, it wont response and after long time it gives Timeout error and I need to contact host provider to kill the app!

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.get( '/', (q, res) => { res.json( { status: "Hello World" } ) } );
app.listen();
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
        "start": "node dist/app.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.0.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: cpanel solutions are not a good choice to deploy nodejs, java or similar languages.

Comment: so what is the actual use of "Setup Node.js APP" option on CPanel?? it is not a decorative option. is it? :)

Comment: Is an attempt to sell something.  From the moment you need to contact to a human to restart or kill the app, is not a good option. Does your cpanel offer, streaming log, git repository, shell access, start/tops/restart actions, webhooks, variables management? Therefore, I tell you "is not a good choice"

Comment: Could you please explain it why they provide nodejs option in cpanel while as you said it is not a good option?! I'm totally agree with you but I can't understand the purpose of that option

Comment: In think is a way to attract new customers. Also its nodejs service is in early stage. If the host provider has  streaming log, git repository, shell access, start/tops/restart actions, webhooks, variables management, etc could be an alternative to heroku.